# Passing reference to middle class just to get some data from instace of first class

Tags: java, design-patterns

how can i bypass following design ?

```
package com.example;

public class A {
    public String[] data;

    public B doFooB() {
        return new B(this);
    }

    public String[] getWhatINeed() {
        return data;
    }
}

class B {
    public A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public C doFooC(A a) {
        return new C(a);
    }
}

class C {
    public A a;

    public C(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String[] doFooC() {
        return a.getWhatINeed();
    }
}
```

I don’t like this approach, because reference to instance of class A is passed first through class B just to get to the class C, where I need only some data from instance of class A.

Thanks for any help in advance !

Comment: Without context, it looks like you don't need B class at all.

Comment: I think context is not important here. But trust me, class B is needed :)

Comment: Without much information, it is hard to understand what you actually want/need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how your classes diagram looks like:

[image: Before]

What is wrong is that class C uses directly class A to retrieve `data`. It is violation of one of programming good practices, called [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) which states:

> Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.

So one should bypass this dependency, by using class B as a proxy. We wil create method `getWhatINeed()` in class B, which will delegate this call to class A. Here is how your code should look like:

```
public class A {
    public String[] data;

    public B doFooB() {
        return new B(this);
    }

    public String[] getWhatINeed() {
        return data;
    }
}

class B {
    public A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public getWhatINeed() {
        return a.getWhatINeed();
    }

    public C doFooC() {
        return new C(this);
    }
}

class C {
    public B b;

    public C(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String[] doFooC() {
        return b.getWhatINeed();
    }
}
```

After this, dependencies between your classes will look like this:

[image]